# Show direct ancestors/descendents only, not siblings/aunts/uncles/cousins

Tags: apex, visualforce, hierarchy

I used unmanged package account inline hierarchy from appexchange :
 https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016chCEAQ

and tweaked the code to use it for custom object.
Below is VF component:

```
<apex:component Controller="AccountStructure">
    <apex:attribute name="currentId" description="This is the Account Id for displaying Acccount Hierarchy" type="String" required="true" assignTo="{!currentId}"/>

    <div class="treeNode">
            <apex:repeat value="{!ObjectStructure}" var="pos" >
            <apex:repeat value="{!pos.levelFlag}" var="flag" first="0">
                <apex:image url="/img/tree/empty.gif" height="16" width="20" rendered="{!IF(flag,false,true)}"/>
                <apex:image url="/s.gif" alt="" width="3" height="16" rendered="{!IF(flag,true,false)}"/>
                <apex:image url="/img/tree/chain.gif" height="16" width="20" rendered="{!IF(flag,true,false)}"/>
            </apex:repeat>

            <span height="16" v="top">

            <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(pos.nodeType=='start',true,false)}">
                <apex:image id="tree_start" url="/img/tree/minusStart.gif" height="16" width="20" title="Click to expand/collapse nested items." onClick="TreeNodeElement.prototype.toggle(this,'{!pos.nodeId}')"/>
                <apex:image id="Icon_start" url="/img/icon/custom51_100/globe16.png" width="16" height="16" rendered="{!IF(pos.currentNode,false,true)}"/>
                <apex:image id="Icon_start_current" url="/img/icon/star16.png" width="16" height="16" rendered="{!IF(pos.currentNode,true,false)}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(OR(pos.nodeType=='parent',pos.nodeType=='parent_end'),true,false)}">
                <apex:image id="Tree_parent" url="/img/tree/minus.gif" rendered="{!IF(pos.nodeType=='parent',true,false)}" height="16" width="20" title="Click to expand/collapse nested items." onClick="TreeNodeElement.prototype.toggle(this,'{!pos.nodeId}')"/>
                <apex:image id="Tree_parent_end" url="/img/tree/minusEnd.gif" rendered="{!IF(pos.nodeType=='parent_end',true,false)}" height="16" width="20" title="Click to expand/collapse nested items." onClick="TreeNodeElement.prototype.toggle(this,'{!pos.nodeId}')"/>                
                <apex:image id="Icon_parent" url="/img/icon/factory16.png" width="16" height="16" rendered="{!IF(pos.currentNode,false,true)}"/>
                <apex:image id="Icon_parent_current" url="/img/icon/star16.png" width="16" height="16" rendered="{!IF(pos.currentNode,true,false)}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(OR(pos.nodeType=='child',pos.nodeType=='child_end'),true,false)}">
                <apex:image id="Tree_child" url="/img/tree/node.gif" rendered="{!IF(pos.nodeType=='child',true,false)}" height="16" width="20" title="Click to expand/collapse nested items." onClick="TreeNodeElement.prototype.toggle(this,'{!pos.nodeId}')"/>
                <apex:image id="Tree_child_current" url="/img/tree/nodeEnd.gif" rendered="{!IF(pos.nodeType=='child_end',true,false)}" height="16" width="20" title="Click to expand/collapse nested items." onClick="TreeNodeElement.prototype.toggle(this,'{!pos.nodeId}')"/>
                <apex:image id="Icon_child" url="/img/icon/desk16.png" width="16" height="16" rendered="{!IF(pos.currentNode,false,true)}"/>    
                <apex:image id="Icon_child_current" url="/img/icon/star16.png" width="16" height="16" rendered="{!IF(pos.currentNode,true,false)}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(pos.nodeType=='end',true,false)}">
                <apex:image id="Tree_end" url="/img/tree/nodeEnd.gif" height="16" width="20"/>&nbsp;
                <apex:image id="Icon_end" url="/img/icon/desk16.png" width="16" height="16" rendered="{!IF(pos.currentNode,false,true)}"/>
                <apex:image id="Icon_end_current" url="/img/icon/star16.png" width="16" height="16" rendered="{!IF(pos.currentNode,true,false)}"/>
            </apex:outputText>

            <apex:outputLink value="/{!pos.account.id}" style="{!IF(pos.currentNode,'font-weight: bold;','')}" styleClass="columnHeadActiveBlack" target="_top">{!pos.account.name}</apex:outputLink>

            </span>
            <div> </div>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(OR(pos.nodeType=='child_end',pos.nodeType=='child'),false,true)}">
                <div id='{!pos.nodeId}'>
            </apex:outputText>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(OR(pos.nodeType=='child_end',pos.nodeType=='child'),true,false)}">
                <div id='{!pos.nodeId}'><apex:image url="/s.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1"/></div>
            </apex:outputText>
            <apex:repeat value="{!pos.closeFlag}" var="close">
                </div>
            </apex:repeat>            

    </apex:repeat>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
</apex:component>
```

APEX CLASS:

```
/**
* To adapt this to anouther Object simply search for "Change" to go to the places 
* where the sObject and query must be changed
*/
public with sharing class AccountStructure{

    //Declare variables
    public String currentId;
    public List<ObjectStructureMap> asm ;
    public Map<String, ObjectStructureMap> masm;
    public List<Integer> maxLevel;

    /**
    * Contructor
    */
    public AccountStructure() {
        this.asm = new List<ObjectStructureMap>{};
        this.masm = new Map<String, ObjectStructureMap>{};
        this.maxLevel = new List<Integer>{};
    }

    /**
    * Allow page to set the current ID
    */
    public void setcurrentId( String cid ){
        currentId = cid;
    }

    /**
    * Return ObjectStructureMap to page
    * @return asm
    */
    public List<ObjectStructureMap> getObjectStructure(){
        asm.clear();
        if ( currentId == null ) {
            currentId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get( 'id' );
        }

        System.assertNotEquals( currentId, null, 'sObject ID must be provided' );
        asm = formatObjectStructure( CurrentId );

        return asm;
    }

    /**
    * Query Account from top down to build the ObjectStructureMap
    * @param currentId
    * @return asm
    */
    public ObjectStructureMap[] formatObjectStructure( String currentId ){

        List<ObjectStructureMap> asm = new List<ObjectStructureMap>{};
        masm.clear();

        //Change below
        List<ADSS_Platform_Account__c> al  = new List<ADSS_Platform_Account__c>{};
        List<ID> currentParent      = new List<ID>{};
        Map<ID, String> nodeList    = new Map<ID, String>{};
        List<String> nodeSortList   = new List<String>{};
        List<Boolean> levelFlag     = new List<Boolean>{};
        List<Boolean> closeFlag     = new List<Boolean>{};
        String nodeId               = '0';
        String nodeType             = 'child';
        Integer count               = 0;
        Integer level               = 0;
        Boolean endOfStructure      = false;

        //Find highest level obejct in the structure
        currentParent.add( GetTopElement( currentId ) );

        //Loop though all children
        while ( !endOfStructure ){

            if( level == 0 ){
                //Change below     
                al = [ SELECT  a.Parent_IB__c, a.OwnerId, a.Name, a.Account__c, a.Id FROM ADSS_Platform_Account__c a WHERE a.id IN : CurrentParent ORDER BY a.Name ];
            } 
            else {
                //Change below      
                al = [ SELECT  a.Parent_IB__c, a.OwnerId, a.Name, a.Account__c, a.Id FROM ADSS_Platform_Account__c a WHERE a.Parent_IB__c IN : CurrentParent ORDER BY a.Name ];
            }

            if( al.size() == 0 ){
                endOfStructure = true;
            }
            else{
                currentParent.clear();
                for ( Integer i = 0 ; i < al.size(); i++ ){
                    //Change below
                    ADSS_Platform_Account__c a = al[i];
                    nodeId = ( level > 0 ) ? NodeList.get( a.Parent_IB__c)+'.'+String.valueOf( i ) : String.valueOf( i );
                    masm.put( NodeID, new ObjectStructureMap( nodeID, levelFlag, closeFlag, nodeType, false, false, a ) );
                    currentParent.add( a.id );
                    nodeList.put( a.id,nodeId );
                    nodeSortList.add( nodeId );
                }

                maxLevel.add( level );                
                level++;
            }
        }

        //Account structure must now be formatted
        NodeSortList.sort();
        for( Integer i = 0; i < NodeSortList.size(); i++ ){
            List<String> pnl = new List<String> {};
            List<String> cnl = new List<String> {};
            List<String> nnl = new List<String> {};

            if ( i > 0 ){
                String pn   = NodeSortList[i-1];
                pnl         = pn.split( '\\.', -1 );
            }

            String cn   = NodeSortList[i];
            cnl         = cn.split( '\\.', -1 );

            if( i < NodeSortList.size()-1 ){
                String nn = NodeSortList[i+1];
                nnl = nn.split( '\\.', -1 );
            }

            ObjectStructureMap tasm = masm.get( cn );
            if ( cnl.size() < nnl.size() ){
                //Parent
                tasm.nodeType = ( isLastNode( cnl ) ) ? 'parent_end' : 'parent';
            }
            else if( cnl.size() > nnl.size() ){
                tasm.nodeType   = 'child_end';
                tasm.closeFlag  = setcloseFlag( cnl, nnl, tasm.nodeType );
            }
            else{
                tasm.nodeType = 'child';
            }

            tasm.levelFlag = setlevelFlag( cnl, tasm.nodeType ); 

            //Change below
            if ( tasm.ADSaccount.id == currentId ) {
                tasm.currentNode = true;
            }
            asm.add( tasm );
        }

        asm[0].nodeType             = 'start';
        asm[asm.size()-1].nodeType  = 'end';

        return asm;
    }

    /**
    * Determin parent elements relationship to current element
    * @return flagList
    */
    public List<Boolean> setlevelFlag( List<String> nodeElements, String nodeType ){

        List<Boolean> flagList = new List<Boolean>{};
        String searchNode   = '';
        String workNode     = '';
        Integer cn          = 0;

        for( Integer i = 0; i < nodeElements.size() - 1; i++ ){
            cn = Integer.valueOf( nodeElements[i] );
            cn++;
            searchNode  = workNode + String.valueOf( cn );
            workNode    = workNode + nodeElements[i] + '.';
            if ( masm.containsKey( searchNode ) ){
                flagList.add( true );
            }
            else {
                flagList.add( false );
            }
        }

        return flagList;
    }

    /**
    * Determin if the element is a closing element
    * @return flagList
    */
    public List<Boolean> setcloseFlag( List<String> cnl, List<String> nnl, String nodeType ){

        List<Boolean> flagList = new List<Boolean>{};
        String searchNode   = '';
        String workNode     = '';
        Integer cn          = 0;

        for( Integer i = nnl.size(); i < cnl.size(); i++ ){
            flagList.add( true );
        }

        return flagList;
    }

    /**
    * Determin if Element is the bottom node  
    * @return Boolean
    */
    public Boolean isLastNode( List<String> nodeElements ){

        String searchNode   = '';
        Integer cn          = 0;

        for( Integer i = 0; i < nodeElements.size(); i++ ){
            if ( i == nodeElements.size()-1 ){
                cn = Integer.valueOf( nodeElements[i] );
                cn++;
                searchNode = searchNode + String.valueOf( cn );
            }
            else {
                searchNode = searchNode + nodeElements[i] + '.';
            }
        }
        if ( masm.containsKey( searchNode ) ){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Find the tom most element in Heirarchy  
    * @return objId
    */
    public String GetTopElement( String objId ){

        Boolean top = false;
        while ( !top ) {
            //Change below
            ADSS_Platform_Account__c a = [ Select a.Id, a.Parent_IB__c From ADSS_Platform_Account__c a where a.Id =: objId limit 1 ];

            if ( a.Parent_IB__c != null ) {
                objId = a.Parent_IB__c;
            }
            else {
                top = true;
            }
        }
        return objId ;
    }

    /**
    * Wrapper class
    */
    public with sharing class ObjectStructureMap{

        public String nodeId;
        public Boolean[] levelFlag = new Boolean[]{};
        public Boolean[] closeFlag = new Boolean[]{};
        public String nodeType;
        public Boolean currentNode;

        /**
        * @Change this to your sObject
        */
        public ADSS_Platform_Account__c ADSaccount;

        public String getnodeId() { return nodeId; }
        public Boolean[] getlevelFlag() { return levelFlag; }
        public Boolean[] getcloseFlag() { return closeFlag; }
        public String getnodeType() { return nodeType; }
        public Boolean getcurrentNode() { return currentNode; }


        /**
        * @Change this to your sObject
        */
        public ADSS_Platform_Account__c getaccount() { return ADSaccount ; }

        public void setnodeId( String n ) { this.nodeId = n; }
        public void setlevelFlag( Boolean l ) { this.levelFlag.add(l); }
        public void setlcloseFlag( Boolean l ) { this.closeFlag.add(l); }
        public void setnodeType( String nt ) { this.nodeType = nt; }
        public void setcurrentNode( Boolean cn ) { this.currentNode = cn; }

        /**
        * @Change this to your sObject
        */
        public void setaccount( ADSS_Platform_Account__c a ) { this.ADSaccount = a; }

        /**
        * @Change the parameters to your sObject
        */
        public ObjectStructureMap( String nodeId, Boolean[] levelFlag,Boolean[] closeFlag , String nodeType, Boolean lastNode, Boolean currentNode, ADSS_Platform_Account__c a ){

            this.nodeId         = nodeId;
            this.levelFlag      = levelFlag; 
            this.closeFlag      = closeFlag;
            this.nodeType       = nodeType;
            this.currentNode    = currentNode;

            //Change this to your sObject  
            this.ADSaccount = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this class is showing me results as per below image :

[image]

I want to display only the yellow highlighted records i dont want to display records which are not directlly linked to record Client3 (like client1, ADSS004, ADSS007)

Can anybody help me here?

Comment: I believe it would be hard to tweak this code to do what you are looking for. The reason is, this code starts with `GetTopElement(..)` and then proceeds to get all children and show them in the tree structure. This way the tree will always show all the children like it is showing now. What you would want to do instead is start with the currentId and keep finding all the parents and complete the structure that way so that any sibling records are ignored.

Comment: So basically I want to get everything in the chain  i.e. all parents as shown + child as well 
so should I create two methods like one for going up and one for going down?
I wanted to use the above one because that works in both direction